# Check boxes to display regardless if they are checked or not

Tags: php

I am writing a script that allows a user to go in and assign flags to an account using check boxes. Once the user selects the check boxes and submits it will write to the database and apply the flags. I have some of the code written that will show the checkboxes that are check but the unchecked ones don't appear. Any help would be great.

```
    $flag["infractions"] = [];
    $sql = "SELECT *
FROM flag_info
INNER JOIN infraction_flags 
ON flag_info.flag_id = infraction_flags.flag_id
WHERE ban_id = ?;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['ban_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    //if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['flag_id'];
        $name = $row['flag_id'];
        $longName = $row['flag_long_name'];
        $checked = $row['ban_id'] ? "checked" : "";
        $flag["infractions"][$id] = ["name" => $name, "checked" => $checked, "longName" => $longName];
            /*echo "<ul><input type='checkbox' name='flag_id[]' value='".$row['flag_id']."'>".$row['flag_long_name']."</input></ul>";*/
        $active = isset($checked); //This is toe check to see if the box is checked

        }

      ?>
      <?php if ($active): ?>
       <?php foreach ($flag["infractions"] as $id=>$flags): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="flags_ID[]" id="flags_<?=$id?>" value="<?=$id?>" <?=$flags["checked"]?>>
        <label for="flags_<?=$id?>">
          <?=htmlspecialchars($flags["longName"])?>
        </label><br/>
      <?php endforeach ?>
      
     <?php else: ?> // This displays the uncheck box(es)
      <?php foreach ($flag["infractions"] as $id=>$flags): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="flags_ID[]" id="flags_<?=$id?>" value="<?=$id?>">
        <label for="flags_<?=$id?>">
          <?=htmlspecialchars($flags["longName"])?>
        </label><br/>
      <?php endforeach ?>
       <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Do you want show all checked checkboxes before all unchecked checkboxes or its not important?

Comment: Either way is fine by me

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need to use `$active` variable

you can try this:

```
$flag["infractions"] = [];
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM flag_info
INNER JOIN infraction_flags 
ON flag_info.flag_id = infraction_flags.flag_id
WHERE ban_id = ?;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['ban_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['flag_id'];
    $name = $row['flag_id'];
    $longName = $row['flag_long_name'];
    $checked = $row['ban_id'] ? "checked" : "";
    $flag["infractions"][$id] = ["name" => $name, "checked" => $checked, "longName" => $longName];
        
    }
}
```

If it's important for you that display all checked checkboxes before all unchecked ckeckboxes you can use it:

```
<!-- // Checked checkboxes -->
<?php if( is_array($flag["infractions"]) && !empty($flag["infractions"])) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($flag["infractions"] as $id=>$flags): ?>
        <?php if( $flags["checked"] ) : ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="flags_ID[]" id="flags_<?=$id?>" value="<?=$id?>" checked>
            <label for="flags_<?=$id?>">
            <?=htmlspecialchars($flags["longName"])?>
            </label><br/>

            <!-- Unset checked item -->
            <?php unset($flag["infractions"][$id]) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- // If exist unchecked checkboxes -->
<?php if( is_array($flag["infractions"]) && !empty($flag["infractions"])) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($flag["infractions"] as $id=>$flags): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="flags_ID[]" id="flags_<?=$id?>" value="<?=$id?>">
        <label for="flags_<?=$id?>">
        <?=htmlspecialchars($flags["longName"])?>
        </label><br/>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If its not important only use it:

```
<?php if( is_array($flag["infractions"]) && !empty($flag["infractions"])) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($flag["infractions"] as $id=>$flags): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="flags_ID[]" id="flags_<?=$id?>" value="<?=$id?>" <?=$flags["checked"]?>>
        <label for="flags_<?=$id?>">
        <?=htmlspecialchars($flags["longName"])?>
        </label><br/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I went with the option that shows both checked and unchecked boxed however it only shows the checked boxes still I went to a record that only had one flag applied and it didn't give me the option to select the unchecked flags.